# Change search page url

Tags: search, search-results

when i click on search button it redirect me to sharepoint serach result page. but i want to redirect it to my customize url.for this i try to change in my master page SearchResultPageURL property it works for only first time .

Comment: Have you tried changing the Search settings under Site Collection Administration? Use the radio button 'Send queries to a custom results page URL' and apply your custom page.

Comment: i am using sharepoint 2010. so in serach setting i have enable radio button "Enable custom scopes" and give serach center url "/layouts/ossserachresults.aspx" now when ii click search button. the url open is "/OSSSearchResults.aspx/Results.aspx" the page showing me correct result . now problem is that it appends my url with "/Results.aspx" due to that my master page ribbon is not visible. i want to know can be remove "/Results.aspx".i want only "/layouts/ossserachresults.aspx".

Comment: issue Fixed. Thanx a lot Aveenav for reply.

Comment: If issue is fixed, you should post the solution as an answer and mark it as your accepted solution